# How to write utf-8 characters to a file using c++

Tags: c++, file-io, unicode, utf-8

How to write  utf-8 characters to a file using c++?

For example,
`utf-8 value=0xc389`
If I write this into a file in binary mode , I have to see characters.

so far I have tried the following

```
unsigned short array[4]={0xc3,0x89,0xc3,0x8a};
std::ofstream file;
file.open("1.txt", std::ios_base::binary);
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(array),sizeof(array));
```

But it takes `0xc3` as single character and it prints its equivalent character of `0xc3` `unicode` value.
Help me how to write the `utf-8` value to file using `c++` in binary mode

Comment: Are you sure you're opening your output file with something that is interpreting it as UTF-8?

Comment: Sorry I dint get u,what do u mean i am just opening the  output file using gedit.

Comment: windows, macos or linux? in windows you have the BOM characters at the start of the file, don't see them in your code.

Comment: iam using linux @claptrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using `short` array when `char` array will solve your purpose?

First of all, in UTF-8, you write byte by byte. If your sequence is a valid UTF-8 byte sequence, then write them byte by byte.

If it is unicode character, first convert your character stream to UTF-8 character as characters beyond 0x7f will be treated differently.

```
//I assume this a valid UTF-8 sequence.
unsigned char array[4]={0xc3,0x89,0xc3,0x8a};
std::ofstream file;
file.open("1.txt", std::ios_base::binary);
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(array),sizeof(array));
```

In case, array is not a UTF-8 sequence but some character, you can use `iconv` on linux to convert to UTF-8.

Comment: can u pls write the code here for the above explanation.Thanks @dbasic